# Is there a way get slice's len/cap address?

Tags: go, slice, memory-address

I know there are `len()` and `cap()` functions that return len/cap of slice, but I want to get address of slice to modify it by hand.

Comment: do you really want to do something so unsafe?

Comment: I can show you how to do it but it should be done by slicing instead. Slice can point to unknown memory and there is no guarantee what can be in there and if it will stay.

Comment: You *can* do this using `unsafe.Pointer` and conversions. But unless you're writing the Go runtime, you *should not* do this at all.

Comment: I just want to mess around with memory. Of course, I most likely wouldn't use that in any serious programs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    // slice of int
    us := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

    // len: 4, cap: 4
    fmt.Printf("len: %d, cap: %v\n", len(us), cap(us))

    hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&us))
    hdr.Cap = 10
    hdr.Len = 100

    // len: 100, cap: 10
    fmt.Printf("len: %d, cap: %v\n", len(us), cap(us))
}
```

Sample output:

```
len: 4, cap: 4
len: 100, cap: 10
```

Comment: Be aware: Code using `unsafe` is, well, unsafe... and it could potentially break with future Go versions, if the underlying memory layout of a slice ever changes.

Comment: @Ignatij But why do you want it? Could you please elaborate a little? What's the use case?

Comment: @shmsr As I've written under my question, this idea was born out of curiosity, it was interesting to see what would happen if I manually access and change slice parameters

Comment: Okay, got it! @Ignatij